# How secure SSH dynamic port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, socks-proxy, socks, socks5

I'm using SSH's dynamic port forwarding to host a socks proxy on localhost. I'm trying to find out if the connection between my computer and the remote server/destination is secured.  Will my ISP or anyone be able to read data sent through the socks connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data inside the ssh tunnel will not be viewable provided you are connecting to the server you intend to.

When you first make the ssh connection, you'll be prompted with the fingerprint of the remote servers key.  You should verify this key to ensure that your connection has not been intercepted and redirected to a server you do not trust.  This depends whether you are concernd with casual snooping or directed efforts to monitor your activity.